# What are the best option to build a jupyter notebook sharing platform

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, data-science, gogs

I have to build a "open science platform" where engineer can build and share their script and jupyter notebook. (and versioning)
One good example could be the kaggle website. There is data and people fork this one to make script from them. People can share, vote, and run jupyter notebook from the website.

Obviously, i did not find opensource platform that fit of hour needs.

Then, i would like to have some advice to build our own platform. 
From some reasearch, i notice 3 solutions:
- Start form fork gogs open source project.(git hosting) and modify directly the source code to meet our needs.
- Take a solution like wordpress or an other solution. Build the "collaborative' part in it, and try to play with webhooks and gogs to keep the versioning.
- The last one i just discover, make it with the "open science framework" project.

Thanks for your answers!